# VLOOKUP logic when range_lookup is TRUE but table_array is not sorted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Excel's VLOOKUP hint tells us to use `range_lookup = TRUE` only when the `table_array` is sorted. However, does anyone know what is the logic that VLOOKUP executes when `range_lookup = TRUE` but table_array is **not sorted**?

For example, I have a table starting from A1 cell as follows:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1000 |
| 3 | 3.9 |
| 4 | 1000 |
| 5 | 3.9 |
| 6 | 3.9 |
| 7 | 3.9 |
| 8 | 3.9 |

With the formula:

```
= VLOOKUP(3.9, A1:A8, 1, TRUE)
```

I get result of `#N/A`.

Changing any of the 1000 in the above table to 3.9, will let my formula output `3.9`.

Extending the table_array to include one more 3.9, and modifying the formula accordingly, gives `3.9` instead of `#N/A`.

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1000 |
| 3 | 3.9 |
| 4 | 1000 |
| 5 | 3.9 |
| 6 | 3.9 |
| 7 | 3.9 |
| 8 | 3.9 |
| 9 | 3.9 |

Formula:

```
= VLOOKUP(3.9, A1:A9, 1, TRUE)
```

However, switching the 1000 and 3.9 in the 4th and 5th cells of this extended table makes the formula output `#N/A` again.

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1000 |
| 3 | 3.9 |
| 4 | 3.9 |
| 5 | 1000 |
| 6 | 3.9 |
| 7 | 3.9 |
| 8 | 3.9 |
| 9 | 3.9 |

I came across this issue when I intended for VLOOKUP to just pick up a value close to 3.9 from the top, in an unsorted table.

However, this behavior of VLOOKUP when `range_lookup = TRUE` with an unsorted `table_array` does not seem to make any sense.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Good question. It's quite confusing, I think. This article may help: https://exceljet.net/how-to-lookup-first-and-last-match. However, if you have XLOOKUP available, I recommend using it and forgetting about VLOOKUP. Alternatively, use INDEX/MATCH or one of the other methods he suggests in that article.

Comment: So you want to find the number the closest to the input or do you want to find the closest that is less than the input number or do you want to find the closest that is greater than the input number?

Comment: Thanks @FlexYourData. After more research, I found that the mechanism that caused the observation I've described is the binary search algorithm that VLOOKUP uses when range_lookup = TRUE.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. To your clarification query, in the unsorted table, I want to find the number that first appears which is greater than my input number. It need not be the closest to it, and I thought the "approximate" mechanism of VLOOKUP could work. After learning the algorithm behind it now, it does not seem to work for my case.

Comment: @ScottCraner, the way to achieve what I want appears to be described here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2549-excel-find-first-last-value-greater-than.html

Took a roundabout, but cool to discover something new about the VLOOKUP mechanism along the way.

Comment: If you want the first that is greater than you would expect 1000 to be returned (using your first table)?

Comment: @ScottCraner, yes if referring to the table in my post, that would be the case. I actually just use the 1000 and 3.9 table to illustrate the seemingly incomprehensible behavior of VLOOKUP when range_lookup = TRUE, which is separate from my actual problem. In my actual problem, the progression starts lower and is more gradual like, 3.5, 3.6, 3.8, etc. Hope this doesn't cause much confusion.

Comment: Then use: `=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:A9)/(A1:A9>=3.9),1)` it will return the first value that is Greater than or equal to 3.9.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the algorithm that VLOOKUP uses when range_lookup = TRUE is the binary search algorithm, instead of a linear search algorithm. This explains the changing #N/A and 3.9 outputs that I have described in my post.

This use of binary search algorithm does not seem well documented, even on Microsoft's own VLOOKUP support page.

I know posting links is not best practice, but the best explanation that I have come across is in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GllJpJxOSvM).

To quote another explanation by [rnelsonee on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/5xzkuz/vlookup_doesnt_seem_to_work_logically_warning_nsfw/demrtf1/):

> Yeah, ordered data is a requirement for the normal default mode. VLOOKUP and MATCH use a binary search where they cut the range in half, look at the value, then go to the spot 25% the way through, or the spot 75% the way through (depending on the value of the 50% being + or - the lookup). It keeps this up until it finds a number larger than the lookup value, but the previous value was <= to the lookup. This is very fast, and considering the first LOOKUP function was written circa 1979, this stuff mattered. Now speed isn't so huge of an issue, but backwards compatibility keeps VLOOKUP using a binary search.
>
> For example, VLOOKUP starts at 110 here, goes to 30, then 40, then 50, then sees 110>50, so it reports 50. Now check this out - we highjack the 30 so VLOOKUP thinks all the low values are in rows 1 and 2. But if we put 110 to 60 then it never even sees that whole bottom half.
>
> Also, text and data area all the same when it comes to lookups - numbers come first, then special chars, then alphabetical order.