# Vlookup search Bug

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, bug

When I use VLookup to auto fill rows from a chart, it works for every search value except searches where the lookup value is CPT-X. In this scenario original formula:

[image]

If I change the lookup value to `"wow"` or `"sad"` it finds the correct value and outputs correctly. Which makes zero sense to me. See images attached.

[image: "wow" input]

Comment: use the forth criterion when trying to find exact match: `=VLOOKUP(B13,$H$2:$O$12,6,FALSE)`  Otherwise the lookup range must be sorted ascending.

Comment: See this answer for an explanation of how VLOOKUP works when the forth criterion is TRUE, which is the default: https://superuser.com/questions/1719222/vlookup-logic-when-range-lookup-is-true-but-table-array-is-not-sorted

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula to:

```
=VLOOKUP(B13,$H$2:$O$12,6,FALSE)
```